# Программа для Убунты для работы с MySQL

Tags: mysql, linux

Какую программу посоветуете для работы с БД MySQL для убунты 10,04? чтоб была похожа на SQL Manager Lite for MySQL

Comment: те кто пишут про консольный mysql, мне интересно, вы вобще с базами данных работали когда нибудь? данные вручную вбивали? use mysql; select * from user; если вас не смущает вывод, то может вам мускул и не нужен, можно же писать на машинном коде и компилировать в голове, долго, зато тру

Answer (score 4):

Не знаю что такое "SQL Manager Lite", но в комплекте убунты и так уже есть прекрасные средства администрирования MySQL.

1. команда mysql. Учите ее параметры. Для поднятия сервера после падения это возможно единственный вариант.
2. mysqladmin. Также консольная, но архи-полезная утилита. Тоже идет сразу в комплекте с mysql
3. phpMyAdmin. Веб-панель для управления MySQL. Требует дополнительно Web-сервер и PHP. Установить дополнительно не проблема, но обычно является стандартным компонентом (L)AMP.

Answer (score 2):

А чем консольный "`mysql -u <user> -p`" не устраивает?

Answer (score 2):

[MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) - довольно удобная программа для администрирования MySql с графическим интерфейсом.

Answer (score 1):

```
CLI - mysql
GUI - MySQL Administrator 
WEB - phpMyAdmin
```

Предпочитаю последнее

Answer (score 0):

Советую использовать [Valentina Studio](http://www.valentina-db.com/en/valentina-studio-overview), это лучший бесплатный инструмент под linux, windows и Mac OX S